# How to delete the progress directory generated by spark -streaming application recieving messages from eventhub

Tags: azure, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

the process directory generated by Eventhubutils library is creating a lot of small files in hdfs.https://github.com/Azure/spark-eventhubs/blob/master/docs/direct_stream.md. due to these small files, there is a lot of load on the namenode .Is there any way to delete the progress directory without disturbing the spark application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxzk0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience , if your current task is executing, the resulting file can't be deleted.

Here, I offer two ways to delete files without code for your reference.

***First Way:***

Because the files on the `HDFS` can be found on `azure blob storage container`, you can delete them directly on the Azure portal. If you don't want to delete files one by one , you can use the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) tool to select all files to delete.

***Second Way:***

You can log on to the cluster machine and use the [**rm** command line:](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)

```
hadoop fs -rm [-f] [-r |-R] [-skipTrash] URI [URI ...]
```

You can find the corresponding `azure blob storage container` path in the [configuration file](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html).

```
wasbs://yourcontainer@youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/testDir/testFile.
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So, do you mean to delete the files older than the retention period of event hub? wont it cause any problem to the continuously running spark streaming job?

Comment: @sivakrishna  From the code you offered (https://github.com/Azure/spark-eventhubs/blob/228e1b4ef8c73ddb7e9e44c4216a86f1f3912e9e/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/eventhubs/EventHubsStreamTest.scala#L423) , I notice that the generate files have timestamp. You could clean up files that you won't use based on the timestamp.